# Curl: get UTF-8 data from site with incorrect charset

Tags: php, curl, character-encoding

I scrape some sites that occasionally have UTF-8 characters in the title, but that don't specify UTF-8 as the charset (qq.com is an example).  When I use look at the website in my browser, the data I want to copy (i.e. the title) looks correct (Japanese or Chinese..not too sure).  I can copy the title and paste it into the terminal and it looks exactly the same.  I can even write it to the DB and when I retrieve from the DB it still looks the same, and correct.

However, when I use cURL, the data that gets printed is wrong.  I can run cURL from the command line or use PHP .. when it's printed to the terminal it's clearly incorrect, and it remains that way when I store it to the DB (remember: the terminal *can* display these characters properly).  I've tried all eligible combinations of the following:

- Setting `CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER` to `true`
- `mb_convert_encoding($html, 'UTF-8')`
- `utf8_encode($html)`
- `utf8_decode($html)`

None of these display the characters as expected.  This is very frustrating since I can get the right characters so easily just by visiting the site, but cURL can't.  I've read a lot of suggestions such as this one: [How to get web-page-title with CURL in PHP from web-sites of different CHARSET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426852/how-to-get-web-page-title-with-curl-in-php-from-web-sites-of-different-charset)

The solution in general seems to be "convert the data to UTF-8."  To be honest, I don't actually know what that means.  Don't the above functions convert the data to UTF-8?  Why isn't it already UTF-8?  What is it, and why does it display properly in some circumstances, but not for cURL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you tried :

`$html = iconv("gb2312","utf-8",$html);`

the `gb2312` was taken from the qq.com headers

Comment: I will give this a shot, but it seems like it would only work if I could get the charset.  What if the site has no charset declaration at all?

Comment: This is the right answer. You were on the right lines with `mb_convert_encoding` and `utf8_encode`, but you didn't specify the source encoding, so it was using the (wrong) default.

Comment: @tandu A common strategy is to see if it is valid UTF-8. If not then assume it is ISO-8859-1. Without it explicitly declaring what the encoding is there isn't much you can do but try and make an educated guess.

Comment: Using the source charset makes this work for both `iconv` and `mb_convert_encoding` .. is one preferred over the other?  @spencercw how do I "see if it is valid UTF-8?"

Comment: I've always used `iconv`, but they both do basically the same thing. You can check if a string is valid UTF-8 using this command: `mb_detect_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', true);`.