# php curl japanese output garbled

Tags: php, curl, character-encoding

Consider following URL:
[click here](http://as.iy.impact-ad.jp/bservers/AAMALL/OENCJP=SJIS/acc_random=20239895/pageid=84849626/AAMB1/SITE=NAVITOP/AREA=NT.TSB/AAMSZ=115X124/AAMB2/SITE=NAVITOP/AREA=NT.TSB/AAMSZ=115X124/AAMB3/SITE=NAVITOP/AREA=NT.TSB/AAMSZ=115X124/AAMB4/SITE=NAVITOP/AREA=NT.TSB/AAMSZ=115X124/AAMB5/SITE=NAVITOP/AREA=NT.TSB/AAMSZ=115X124/AAMB6/SITE=NAVITOP/AREA=NT.TSB/AAMSZ=115X124/AAMB7/SITE=NAVITOP/AREA=NT.TSB/AAMSZ=115X124/AAMB8/SITE=NAVITOP/AREA=NT.TSB/AAMSZ=115X124)

There is some encoding into Japanese characters. Firefox browser on my PC is able to detect it automatically and show the characters. For Chrome, on the other hand, I have to change the encoding manually to "Shift_JIS" to see the japanese characters.

If I try to access the content via PHP-cURL, the encoded text appears garbled like this

> ���ϕi�̂��ƂȂ��I�݂��Ȃ̃N�`�R�~�T�C�g�������������i�A�b�g�R�X���j�ɂ��܂����I

I tried:

```
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'Shift_JIS');
```

I also tried (after downloading the curl response):

```
  $output_str = mb_convert_encoding($curl_response, 'Shift_JIS', 'auto');
  $output_str = mb_convert_encoding($curl_response, 'SJIS', 'auto');
```

But that does not work either.

Here is the full code

```
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'Connection: keep-alive'
    ));

    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'SJIS');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Might it be compressed? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310650/decode-gzipped-web-page-retrieved-via-curl-in-php

Comment: could be. How to deal with it in cURL?

Comment: It's explained on the page I linked to

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not the case.

Comment: How about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447601/curl-get-utf-8-data-from-site-with-incorrect-charset

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That page doesn't return valid HTML, it's actually Javascript.  If you fetch it with curl and output it, add `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=shift_jis');` to your code and when you load it in Chrome the characters will display properly.

Since the HTML doesn't specify the character set, you can specify it from the server using `header()`.

To actually convert the encoding so it will display properly in your terminal, you can try the following:

**Use [`iconv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) to convert to UTF-8**

```
$curl_response = iconv('shift-jis', 'utf-8', $curl_response);
```

**Use [`mb_convert_encoding()`](http://php.net/mb_convert_encoding) to convert to UTF-8**

```
$curl_response = mb_convert_encoding($curl_response, 'utf-8', 'shift-jis');
```

Both of those methods worked for me and I was able to see Japanese characters displayed correctly on my terminal.

UTF-8 should be fine, but if you know your system is using something different, you can try that instead.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am trying to access Japanese characters through php script. I cannot use browser. Is it possible?

Comment: @hvs Just use the `iconv()` method. I just tested it, works just fine. You can use it in a regular PHP script and not a webpage.

Comment: @hvs, `mb_convert_encoding()` should work as well. In your original code you used incorrect order of parameters to it. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

Comment: Hi Sorry for getting back to you so late. I was caught up in other things and frankly did not expect an answer after waiting for long time. Your mb_convert_encoding suggestion works!! Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will output the Japanese characters correctly in the browser:-

```
<?php

// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $setUrlHere);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

// grab URL content
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=shift_jis');
echo $response;
```

Comment: Cannot use browser since it is  a php script running on server and writing straight into db.